# "Save as Live Template" menu item disappeared in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, live-templates

I am running Android Studio 1.3.2. Under the Tools menu I used to have "Save as Live Template" item (just above Save File as Template). But now it is gone and I can't make live templates. How do I get the menu item back?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it back. Here's how (Observe that the Preferences menu on Mac might be called something else on other platforms, like Settings or similar).

1. Go to Preferences/Appearance & Behavior/Menus and Toolbars/Main menu/Tools/Tools Basic Group
2. Select "Save File as template..."
3. Click on Move Up button.
4. Click on OK button.